# Bugcheck error D1

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, bsod

I have a **Dell PowerEdge R210 II Server**, which is running **Windows Server 2012 R2 SP1**, and it is randomly rebooting with this error :
**Bugcheck** 0x000000D1 (0x000000000000000C, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff80001b04a16).

I tried to look up this error code and debug the dump file, although i am not familiar with this kind of practices, and i found that the error is due to **bxnd60a.sys**, which is a driver for an NIC adapter (**Broadcom BCM5716C NetXtreme II GigE - client NDIS VBD** in my case), according to what i found on some forums.
But when trying windows auto upgrade, it says that the driver is up to date, and also after trying to manually install the driver, the problem is still here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a solution, because my server stopped rebooting. 
All you have to do is to change some properties of the NIC adapter :

1. Disable Large Send Offload in the adapter configuration pan
 2. Disable TCP Chimeny by entering this command : **netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled**

Answer (score -1):

When I disabled the LSO, the NIC became immediately disabled and would not re-enable.  I had to re-enable LSO to bring the NIC back online.

Comment: This is not an answer. please have a look at this [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)